Minimize the result of matrix multiplication with a linear cost function
$\mathbf{A}$ is a square invertible matrix of order $n$. $\mathbf{y}$ is an $n$-vector (column orientation) where some elements are given and the rest are unknown. Find the unknown values of $\mathbf{y}$ $y_m$...$y_n$ to minimize a linear cost function $c$ where $c$ must also be greater than some given constant.
$$
\mathbf{y} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
\vdots\\
\hline
y_m\\
\vdots\\
y_n\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
c =
(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y})
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
2^0\\
\vdots\\
2^{n-1}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Note: I'm not sure if it's relevant, but elements of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are $0$ or $1$ and operations done in GF(2).
I can do this by hand on paper for 3x3 by doing the matrix multiplication symbolically and choosing values of $y_m$...$y_n$ by inspection, but I don't know how to generalize it for larger values of $n$.
Please be gentle, I'm very early in my self-study of linear algebra. For context, this is inspired by https://everyuuid.com/ where the goal is to design a random permutation from $\{0\dots2^n-1\} \rightarrow \{0\dots2^n-1\}$ with the additional goal of being able to generate "search results" in input-order where some bits of the output are specified. $n = 122$ in this case so any kind of exhaustive search is unfeasible. I'm using multiplication by a randomly-generated $\mathbf{A}$ or $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ to implement the permutation. In practice I'm also using the affine transformation trick where $\mathbf{A}$ is of order $n+1$ with the bottom row being all $0$s then a $1$ and $\mathbf{y}$ is augmented with a $1$ so that $0 \nrightarrow 0$. I assume this doesn't matter for the purposes of this question.

I'm not sure I understand. If the operations are those of $GF(2)$ then $2^n\cdot y=0$ for all $y\in GF(2)$ and $n>0$. Also, there is no natural order in $GF(2)$ in that we cannot meaningfully say that one element would be larger than the other. Can you explain?

c and 2^n are regular integers. c is just the bits of Ay interpreted as an integer in base 2.

Let us define a few names and notation:

$m \le n$ is the number of elements of y you already know
$A_{a, b}$ is the element in the a-th row and b-th column in A
$y_a$ is the a-th element of y ($0$-indexed, so progressing from $0$ to $n-1$ for a n-vector)

Note that the k-th element of Ay depends only on y and the k-th line of A.
Ay = $\left[\begin{matrix} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} y_kA_{0, k} \\ \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} y_kA_{1,k} \\ \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} y_kA_{2,k}\\ \vdots \\ \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} y_kA_{n-1,k} \end{matrix}\right] + \left[\begin{matrix} \sum_{k=m}^{n-1} y_kA_{0, k} \\ \sum_{k=m}^{n-1} y_kA_{1, k}\\ \sum_{k=m}^{n-1} y_kA_{2, k}\\ \vdots \\ \sum_{k=m}^{n-1}y_kA_{n-1, k} \end{matrix}\right]$
Let us call these two terms $c_1$ and $c_2$
$c_1$ is immediately computable as soon as you generate A because it uses only the known terms of y.
$c_2$ contains all of your unknowns. Note also that as you are doing operations on GF(2), $c_{2_k}$ is the sum of the $y_l$ such that $l \ge m$ and $A_{k, l} = 1$, and it is equivalent to the parity of the number of non-null $y_l$ ($l$ belonging to   $\left\{  l | A_{k,l} = 1 \right\}$).
As you want to minimize c, you want $c_{n-l}=0\hspace.5cm \forall 0\le l\le p,\hspace.25cm p\in \mathbb{N}$, which is equivalent to finding the $y_k$ such that $c_2=c_1$ (at least, such that as many of their most significant digits are equal as possible).
Now, we have a system of equations $c_2=c_1$, which you can present as an $n\times n$ matrix and solve using Gaussian elimination to find the $y_k$ such that $c=0$ (or negate the appropriate bits of $c_1$ to create $c_{bis}$ = $c_1+c_{min}$, where $c_{min}$ is the minimum value you want for c, shown as a column vector). If the system has no solutions, remove the equations corresponding to the least significant digits of c until it has at least one solution.
Of course, this is not rigorous, I need more than this textbox to make proper drafts, think about terminology and LaTeX, etc., but it should give you ideas for a few useful transformations and the criteria you want to look for.

Is it ok if I edit your answer for formatting? Splitting the knowns and unknowns into separate objects, as you have done with c1 and c2, is one of the first things I was trying and failing to do, so that's great. I'm currently trying to figure out if they can be defined in terms of regular matrix operations.

@GavinWahl Please do, I know it's not pretty and I'm rambling more than demonstrating ; and both c1 and c2 can be defined in terms of regular matrix operations, they are Ay1 and Ay2, with y1 containing 0s instead of the unknown cells of y, and y2 containing 0s instead of the known cells (y1 = [1 0 1 1 ... | 0 0 ...0 ]T (with the bar separating k=m the known and unknown parts, and y2 = [ 0 0 ... 0  |ym ... yn ]T )
